# MVC3 looping through the data & displaying in correct format

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looping through the data and I want to show 3 items per line, each item in a div.
Without knowing how many items the model currently contains.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="content">
          @item.StudentName
        </div>
         <div>
          @item.StudentId
        </div>
    }
```

Please provide example, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @{int i = 1;}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div style="float:left;">
            <div class="content">
                @item.StudentName
            </div>
            <div>
                @item.StudentId
            </div>
        </div>
i++;
        if(i%3==0)
        {
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the example, can you please explain why you are dividing i % 3?

Comment: i % 3 it's means remainder of the division.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead of a foreach, then when your index is divisible by 3 add a new row